# How to solve a problem about inconsistency of info about installed packages after upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04?

Tags: apt, unity, package-management, launcher

The inconsistency problem which concerns me is actually quite specific. But after three days of internet searching I can not find a solution. The following describes it:

Enter the "Activities" environment. Search in the little search window for anything beginning with "py" and what comes up is "No results." Or click on the 9-dot icon on the launcher bar to display all packages. And, indeed, one does not find any package or application beginning with the character string "py".

The outcome described above is in a complete contradiction with the output of `sudo apt list --installed py*` which pulls up approximately 6 pages of output. Moreover, the second line in those six pages refers to the following package, which will now be used as an example which manifests the problem:

```
pysolfc/focal,focal,now 2.6.4-3 all [installed]
```

Even more amazing, if one enters `pysolfc` at a command prompt in an xterm and hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the application runs very well, with no apparent glitches whatsoever.

But the fact that `pysolfc` can be run from a command prompt and is duly listed as an installed package by the standard and basic package handler, `apt`, in addition to a huge list of Python-related this and that, is in complete contradiction with the fact that the Activities panel simply can not find any of these packages, and can thus add none of them to the "Favorites" list which puts launching icons on the launcher (or is the official name of it launcher?, button bar?, dock?, or yet something else?).

So all of my web searches came up empty. All of the results were trying to explain to me yet again how to make sure with `apt` that my installation is complete (which it is; I have run those options, too, with no negative results). This problem is therefore a total mystery to me, and so I ask about it here. What can one do to solve this problem, or a similar problem? If apt and the Activities search are looking in two different places for their information, then how to reconcile them?

Comment: Since the package includes the .desktop file, it should show up. Try re-installing the package (`sudo apt install --reinstall pysolfc`). If it still fails, then please file a bug report (`ubuntu-bug pysolfc`)

Comment: There is something wrong between GNOMEs Hell and `pysolfc.desktop` file. I can see the icon at least in MATE.

Comment: @user535733: Problem still present after reinstall. Also, there _must_ be applications with name starting with py and the search finds none of them. And clicking the 9-dot icon does not display any such app, either. So I suspect that the problem is not just with pysolfc. What do you think?

Comment: @Norbert: I suspect that we agree about Gnome. I am a long-time Slackware user, though new to Ubuntu. Thus, I am not completely sure what a .desktop file is. And what is MATE? I will be glad to look for the icon with it, but I have never used it before.

Comment: @TheodoreKilgore I think the Gnome developers cannot fix a problem that they do not know about. Report the bug.